# phpmailer not sending attachments

Tags: phpmailer, attachment, email-attachments

Does anybody have idea why my phpmailer dont want to send attachments? There are no errors, I tried every possible file location, and i'm still receiving just plain text mails...

```
require '../phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
            require '../phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';

            $mail = new PHPMailer;

                                           // Enable verbose debug output

            $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
              // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
            $mail->Host = 'serwerxxx.home.pl';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
                            // SMTP username
            $mail->Username = 'my@mail';                 // SMTP username                         // SMTP password
            $mail->Password = 'mypass';                           // SMTP password
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
            $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

            $mail->From = 'my@mail.com';
            $mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
            // Add a recipient
            $mail->addAddress('mail@mail');               // Name is optional

                 // Add attachments
            $mail->AddAttachment("c20.jpg", "c20.jpg");    // Optional name                                // Set email format to HTML

            //$mail->AddAttachment("c20.jpg"); 
            //$mail->AddAttachment("../img/c20.jpg"); 
            //$mail->AddAttachment($_SERVER['../img/c20.jpg'])); 

            $mail->Subject = 'Here is the ółsubject'.$imie.' '.$nazwisko;
            $mail->Body    = 'das'.$format_wydruku1.'  '.$ile1.'This is the HTML messagóóęęe body <b>in SŁŁŚŚśśśłłóóbold!</b>';
            $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

            if(!$mail->send()) {
                echo 'Message could not be sent.';
                echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            } else {
                echo 'Message has been sent';
            }
```

Comment: You've based your code on an old example - are you also using an old example of PHPMailer? Are you checking return values of `addAttachment`? Have you tried absolute paths? Try enabling exceptions with `$mail = new PHPMailer(true);`

Comment: -it's a copy from readme found on my phpmailer instalation
- there is problem with accessing files... don't know why because mail() has no problems with it
-i tried absolute paths

Comment: So what do the return values say?

Comment: 2015-06-23 20:26:59 Brak dostępu do pliku: img/c20.jpg 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'phpmailerException' with message 'Brak dostępu do pliku: img/c20.jpg' in /phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php:2186 Stack trace: #0 /test2/index.php(137): PHPMailer->addAttachment('img/c20.jpg') #1 {main} thrown in /phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php on line 2186

brak dostępu do pliku: lack of access to the file(?)

Comment: If that's from the readme, you must be using an old version. Make sure you have the latest from github. PHPMailer isn't doing anything magic, it just checks that it can read the file using [`is_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) before reading it, so read the docs on that to see why it might be failing.

Comment: Saying `mail()` has no problem with it makes no sense - `mail()` doesn't read files at all!

Answer (score 3):

Took me a while to figure this out too, for me it was a path problem - this solved it for me:

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/rest/of/your/path/to.pdf");
```

Comment: LEGEND! saved me a lot of hassle!